# How did Bell Labs start to work on Project MAC?

Tags: unix, mainframe

Did Bell Labs approach MIT or was it the other way around? Did participating in Project MAC come from researchers requesting management at Bell Labs/MIT or did management make the decision due to dealing with other managers in each of the two organizations? Did it grow out of an informal arrangement into a formal one?

Some background:

In 1962 Robert M. Fano at MIT wrote the Project MAC proposal to J.C.R. Licklider at ARPA. The proposal was accepted and that was the start of Project MAC. Corby said it officially started January 1, 1963.

In 1964, before joining the Computer System Research department at Bell Labs, Denis Ritchie was a graduate student at Harvard. That year, he worked part-time at MIT on Project MAC then. Also in November of 1964 members of the Computer System Research department at Bell Labs were working on Project. DMR joined BTL in 1967.

Edward E. David, Jr., a manager at Bell Labs, was considered by Corbato to be the leader of the pro-Multics faction there. David co-authored *Some Thoughts About the Social Implications Of Accessible Computing* with Fano in 1964 (published in 1965). This suggest he was involved early on with Bell Labs working on Project MAC.

Sam Morgan said in an interview that Alexander ("Sandy") G. Fraser was the principal person who promoted Multics and who advertised it.

Peter G. Neumann wrote that the first real get-together of the Multics team (MIT, Bell Labs, and GE-[later]-Honeywell) took place at an AT&T training center in Hopewell, NJ, the week of Memorial Day 1965.

Sources:

- [The Unix System; the beginning: oral history, Michael S. Mahoney, 1989](https://www.worldcat.org/title/122448530)
- [Interview with Dennis Ritchie](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehos/mike/transcripts/ritchie.htm) Interview from Michael S. Mahoney's book.
- [Dennis Ritchie Thesis](https://dmrthesis.net/grad-school-years/)
- [My Life, Joel Moses](https://web.archive.org/web/20061206232003/http://esd.mit.edu/Faculty_Pages/moses/moses_memoirs.pdf)
- [Oral history interview with Fernando J. Corbató](https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/107230)
- [Some Thoughts About the Social Implications of Accessible Computing](https://multicians.org/fjcc6.html)
- [An Interview with Peter G. Neumann](http://www.csl.sri.com/users/neumann/login17.pdf)
- [Interview with Sam Morgan](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehos/mike/transcripts/morgan.htm) from Michael S. Mahoney's book.
- [Multics Dates](https://multicians.org/chrono.html)

Comment: Variety of material in MIT archives. I’m not near them do… https://archivesspace.mit.edu/agents/corporate_entities/912

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the few old Project MAC TRs I have. Kernighan, in his book UNIX: A History And A Memoir (2020) says only "Multics was going to be a big job, since it involved new software, and new hardware with more capabilities than the IBM 7094, _so MIT enlisted two other organizations to help_. ... Bell Labs, which had a great deal of experience from creating its own systems since the early 1950s, was to collaborate on the operating system." (emphasis is mine.) 1/2

Comment: He also specifically mentions the following Bell Labs researchers as working on Multics from 1966 through 1969: Doug McIlroy (PL/I), Dennis Ritchie (device I/O), Ken Thompson (I/O subsystem), Vic Vyssotsky "in charge of the Bell Labs part of Multics, a partner with [Corbato]", and Peter Neumann, "who had taken over Vic Vyssotsky's role when Vic moved ...". 2/2

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to get Kernighan's book. I'm planning on reviewing the "Switched Output" interviews. I remember they did talk about Multics. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT8Ms9NT2xpb6yBvtVpBXzUoIMAhDu0G9

Comment: Several things: (1) the technical communities were smaller and more close knit with everyone knowing everyone else. (2) companies would not think twice about helping on government funded projects. (3) Both MIT and Bell Labs had long histories (since WWII) of such cooperation with the US government.

Comment: @JonCuster Quite relevant points - including the US being in a constant prolonged war at that time.

Comment: Also, looking at Licklider's Wikipedia entry, while he was at MIT in the 1950's he was involved with establishing the MIT Lincoln Laboratory (government contract lab), as well as the SAGE project (involving Western Electric, AT&T's manufacturing arm). In 1957 he left to go to BBN (developing time sharing), and then in 1962 went to ARPA, then in 1964 back to MIT. He clearly had excellent connections across all the major players and probably just asked folks to get involved. Just for fun, he also helped found Infocom. Pretty seminal career, for sure.

Comment: Philip ("Phil") McCord Morse worked at Bell Labs June-Sept. 1929. In 1956 Phil Morse started the Computation Center at MIT and became its director until 1967.

Comment: "Some Thoughts ..." contains the statement "If every significant action is recorded in the mass memory of a community computer system, and programs are available for analyzing them, the daily activities of each individual could become open to scrutiny" - wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corbato said that Edward E. David of Bell Labs approached Robert Fano of MIT requesting that Bell Labs join Project MAC.

[Multics Reunion: Early Days, Project MAC, CTSS, and Multics, CSAIL video, May 29, 2014, (49:37 video).](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/video/talks/mac50/multics/multics_corbato.mp4) His statement is at 25:12.

Comment: awesome find!  good video too

Comment: Thanks. Somewhere in my research I ran across something that claims Ed David became ostracized after Bell Labs pulled out of Project MAC and he resigned.